# How do I get a continuous, clean gradient on my website?

Tags: html, css

I've been learning HTML and CSS in the hopes of building my own website and discovered the gradient function. Applying it to the body of my website works, however it's not a single continuous gradient - rather, it seems to be copied over and over again like this.

**My WIP website**

[image: My WIP website.]

I was expecting one clean, continuous gradient, much like this:

**The gradient I expected**

[image: The gradient I expected]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly did you use. But simply using `linear-gradient` should work. Here's a code sample

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b388eb 0%, black 100%);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are almost there. Here's the code that should work:

background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(28,28,28) 0%, rgb(62,39,84) 75%);

The 1st argument: '0deg',  means the gradient layers are horizontal. Please feel free to modify the colours as per your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are almost there. Here's the code that should work:

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(28,28,28) 0%, rgb(62,39,84) 75%);
```

The 1st argument: '0deg',  means the gradient layers are horizontal. Please feel free to modify the colours as per your choice.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot :) I also discovered that just adding 'html' worked for some reason